# Generating same result with bindec on different systems

Tags: php, binary, decimal

I am curious if it is possible to generate the same results with bindec method in php, on different systems.

The thing is, my function(which uses the bindec method) works perfectly when I test on my Windows 7 64 bit machine, but when I transfer the code to my web server(running linux), I get different results. I have narrowed my problem down to the bindec method, so I know that it is causing the problem.

Thanks,
Rob

Here is the function. I was in need of the XOR operator, but that was generating a different result on my machine and my server, so I wrote my own to see if that would work.

```
function MyXOR($input, $key){
    $bin_data = decbin($input);
    $bin_key = decbin($key);
    $result_string = "";
    $len_data = strlen($bin_data);
    $len_key = strlen($bin_key);
    for($i = 0; $i < $len_data; $i++){
        if($bin_data{$i} == $bin_key{$i % $len_key}){
                $result_string .= 0;
            } else {
                $result_string .= 1;
        }
    }

    return bindec($result_string);
}
```

Comment: Please can you post the function code? There is no reason for `bindec()` to give different results on different OSes, it's just a form of Math function, and Math is the same everywhere... The only reason you could ever get a different result is it one of the systems is running PHP <4.1.0 and you pass in a *very* large number.

Comment: Actually, `bindec()` may work differently on 32-bit machines when converting values larger than 32 bits because PHP will convert their value to `float`.

Comment: is the web server a 32bit system? in that case you might get different results, if the integer is to large to fit the integer type. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php => Changelog

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja +1 for good point, although this shouldn't make practical difference under 99.9% of circumstances - The OP doesn't specify *what* the difference between his results is, so it's hard to know what the problem is and whether that would affect anything...

Comment: I posted my function, and I do believe my server is 32 bit.

Comment: @RobertSmith ...and is your machine 32-bit as well? Also, what do you pass in, and what results do you get at both sides? What are you expecting - i.e. which machine produces the "wrong" result? Also, does your function produce the same results as the XOR operator?

Comment: I run a 64 bit machine.

The result I am receiving on my system is 407902501 and the result I am receiving on the server is 2401053088725080357. I am XORing -956454966 with 0xDEADBEEF. I do receive the same result with the XOR operator on my system. But I receive -3887064795 with the XOR operator on my server.

Comment: 407902501 is the proper result.

Comment: Very odd. I have just run this script: `<?php echo -956454966 ^ 0xDEADBEEF; ?>` on 3 32-bit machines (2 Windows, 1 Linux) and 2 64-bit machines (1 Windows, 1 Linux) and I cannot get anything other than `407902501`. Are you 100% sure it is this operation that is the problem, and not what you are doing with the result?

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. Could it be a PHP configuration that is affecting the result? And if so, which one?